# Supabase Authentication: Why Doesn't SignUp with Existing Account Log In When 'autoconfirm' Is ON?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, supabase, supabase-database

I'm using the `supabase.auth.signUp` function in my code, expecting a logged-in session when the server has "autoconfirm" ON. However, when signing up with an existing account, it doesn't sign in as expected. Here's the code snippet:

```js
const handleSignUp = async () => {
  await supabase.auth.signUp({
    email,
    password,
    options: {
      emailRedirectTo: `${location.origin}/auth/callback`,
    },
  });
  router.refresh();
}
```

Is the default configuration of Supabase's "autoconfirm" set to off? If so, where can I find and change this configuration? If the default is on, what could be the issue causing this behavior? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After researching this doubt of mine I think this is why:

If you signUp and have an existing user email, then Supabase returns fake info to try an avoid a security leak.

The confirm setting only applies to a new user.
[image]

If on then you will get redirected if user is new and they need to confirm.
If off then you get a real user session back, or a fake user if they already exist.

Here is where I got this information, credits to GaryAustin1
https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/16760#discussioncomment-6809218